# Can a trigger be attached to a Custom Setting?

Tags: apex, customsetting

I know triggers can be added to SObjects. Can the be added to Custom Settings as well? If so, then what would the apex look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently, triggers are not allowed on custom settings. If you're talking about custom settings in a managed package and wanting better validation, control, and the ability to add logic on the creation or update of a custom setting, you could always make the custom setting protected and then provide a Visualforce interface for creating and updating settings. This would give you the hooks you want into apex logic from settings DML operations and it would also hide the ability for users to update settings through the Custom Settings menu in Setup.

Also, here is an IdeaExchange idea for validation and triggers on custom settings:
[Triggers or field validations for Custom Settings](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gv5nAAA)